# Simple way to ignore promise rejection

Tags: javascript

In order to deal with both cases where the user already exists and not exists yet, I wrote a code like this.

```
return createUser({uid})
    .catch(() => {}) // ignore uid-already-exists error
    .then(() => createCustomToken(uid))
```

This code works as expected, but I think `.catch(() => {})` is not simple code.

Is there a better way to ignore promise rejection?

Comment: This approach is fine, maybe looks not that good, but it's legit. Don't worry about it.

Comment: It hardly gets simpler than that.

Comment: Is there no `getOrCreateUser` function that doesn't cause rejections when the user already exists?

Comment: In the actual code, `createUser` is Firebase Admin SDK's `admin.auth().createUser()`.
I read [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth), but it seems there are no methods like `getOrCreateUser`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return createUser({id}) .catch((error) => {void error}) .then(() => createCustomUser(id))
```